# How can I delay in a Linux interrupt handler (I know sleeping usually not possible)

Tags: c, linux, delay, interrupt-handling

I'm working on an embedded Linux ARM system that needs to react to a power failure signal by turning off some power supplies (via GPIO control) in a specific sequence. This process needs to start as soon as possible, so I've installed an interrupt handler to detect this power failure.

The problem is that we need to introduce a little bit of delay between turning each supply off. I understand that delays are not usually allowed in an interrupt handler, but it's totally okay if this handler never returns (power is failing!).

I'm trying to introduce a delay by using the method described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436478/create-a-small-delay-in-a-linux-interrupt-handler), but I can't for the life of me actually cause a measurable delay (observed on an oscilloscope).

*What am I doing wrong, and how can I do it right?*

What follows is the relevant code.

```
/* This function sets en_gpio low, then waits until pg_gpio goes low. */
static inline void powerdown(int en_gpio, int pg_gpio)
{
    /* Bring the enable line low. */
    gpio_set_value(en_gpio, 0);
    /* Loop until power good goes low. */
    while (gpio_get_value(pg_gpio) != 0);
}

/* This is my attempt at a delay function. */
#define DELAY_COUNT 1000000000
static void delay(void)
{
    volatile u_int32_t random;
    volatile u_int32_t accum;
    volatile u_int32_t i;

    get_random_bytes((void*)&random, 4);
    accum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < DELAY_COUNT; i++)
        accum = accum * random;
}

/* This is the interrupt handler. */
static irqreturn_t power_fail_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    powerdown(VCC0V75_EN, VCC0V75_PG);
    delay();
    powerdown(DVDD15_EN, DVDD15_PG);
    delay();
    powerdown(DVDD18_EN, DVDD18_PG);
    delay();
    powerdown(CVDD1_EN, CVDD1_PG);
    delay();
    powerdown(CVDD_EN, CVDD_PG);
    /* It doesn't matter if we get past this point. Power is failing. */
    /* I'm amazed this printk() sometimes gets the message out before power drops! */
    printk(KERN_ALERT "egon_power_fail driver: Power failure detected!\n");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

Comment: `accum` will **overflow** with a very high frequency ... which uses additional, unpredictable cycles and is generally a **very** bad idea - exchange `volatile u_int32_t accum;` for `volatile u_int64_t accum;` if possible, everything else is just _bad code_

Comment: Note that there is already good-to-use delay functions in kernel (`udelay()` for **micro**seconds delay and `mdelay()` for **milli**seconds delay). You just need to include `<linux/delay.h>` header. There is no need to reinvent the wheel :) Anyway, see my answer below, you won't need to use delays at all with it.

Comment: What an actual criteria for your failure signal handling? I mean, how much time is allowed between two events: 1. signal arrived 2. actual power-off actions are happening. The whole design (and API involved) strictly depends on this criteria. So how fast all the thing should be handled? And also what is exactly values of delays you are talking about?

Comment: @SamProtsenko We're guaranteed 10 ms before power is actually gone. without the delays, the interrupt handler has the rails down in about 200 microseconds. I'd like to put about 100 us between bringing each one down.

Comment: @specializt I appreciate the feedback, but if you're going to say "*bad code*", it would be more helpful to elaborate as to why.

Comment: @Steve So the whole power-off procedure should take no more than 10 ms just after failure signal arrived? It changes everything, you should have added this in your question. Anyway, in that case all work probably should be done in hard IRQ handler.

Comment: @Steve Try to use `gpiod_set_raw_value()` and `gpiod_get_raw_value()` along with standard `usleep()`/`msleep()` functions. Write back if it helps. If no -- try to use threaded IRQ approach from my answer and see how it's going. Linux is not a RTOS, so you can't guarantee anything anyway, so threaded IRQ approach may be OK in your case. I'd go with threaded IRQ approach in any case.

Comment: @Steve Well feel free to ask questions if you want to know something. The term "bad code" can be quite the large subject - something particular, perhaps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `delay` functions in hard IRQ handlers is usually bad idea, because **interrupts are disabled** in hard IRQ handler and system will hang until your hard IRQ function is finished. On the other hand, you can't use `sleep` functions in hard IRQ handler since hard IRQ is **atomic context**.

Taking all that into the account, you may want to use [threaded IRQ](https://lwn.net/Articles/302043/). This way hard IRQ handler is only wakes **bottom half** IRQ handler (which executed in kernel thread). In this threaded handler you can use regular `sleep` functions.

To implement threaded IRQ instead of regular IRQ, just replace your `request_irq()` function with `request_threaded_irq()` function. E.g. if you have requesting IRQ like this:

```c
ret = request_irq(irq, your_irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED,
                  dev_name(&dev->dev), chip);
```

You can replace it with something like this:

```c
ret = request_threaded_irq(irq, NULL, your_irq_handler,
                           IRQF_ONESHOT | IRQF_SHARED,
                           dev_name(&dev->dev), chip);
```

Here `NULL` means that the standard hard IRQ handler will be used (which is only wakes threaded IRQ handler), and `your_irq_handler()` function will be executed in kernel thread (where you can call `sleep` functions). Also `IRQF_ONESHOT` flag should be used when requesting threaded IRQ.

It also should be mentioned that there is [managed](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/devres.txt) version of`request_threaded_irq()` function, called `devm_request_threaded_irq()`. Using it (instead of regular `request_threaded_irq()`) allows you to omit `free_irq()` function in your driver exit function (and also in error path). I would recommend you use `devm_*` function (if your kernel version already has it). But don't forget to remove all the `free_irq()` calls in your driver if you decided to go with `devm_*`.

### TL;DR

Replace your `request_irq()` with `request_threaded_irq()` (as it shown above) and you will be able to use `sleep` in your IRQ handler.

Comment: I tried this, but the interrupt didn't seem to trigger. I'm not exactly sure why... So I went back to my original interrupt, and lo-and-behold, it wasn't even triggering. I had the pin configured wrong! I ended up back with mostly my original code, with some loops to implement the delay, so everything happens in the hard interrupt, and all is working.

Comment: Great! And in your case it may be the best solution (to use hard IRQ handler only), taking into the account your 10 ms requirement. The only thing I would recommend you -- is to get rid of your custom-made loop-based delay and use `udelay()` for doing your delay (in microseconds).

Comment: `udelay()` works in interrupt context? I'll have to try that. I (wrongly) assumed it didn't work due to my other ... failure.

Comment: `udelay()` doesn't sleep, so yes, it works fine in atomic contexts (like hard IRQ handler). Just be sure not to use any `sleep` functions, for they are actually do sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rearchitect this into two parts:

1. An interrupt handler
2. An application which waits for the interrupt handler, and then does the timed logic.

As you have experienced, sleeping in an IRQ handler is *bad*.  So is any significant busy waiting as it kills the responsiveness of the rest of the system.

The specific mechanism for the interaction could be any of several means.

If a Linux device driver were used, it could accept read() operations and return something (like how long the wait was, or even single byte of zero) when an interrupt occurs.  So the application would open the device, do a blocking read() and when it returns successfully (without error) do whatever logic is required all in user mode at (maybe) normal priority.

Comment: I'm afraid that the time this would take might be too slow to power off the rails before power really does die. Once the interrupt occurs, everything outside the interrupt doesn't matter any more.

Comment: @Steve:  This won't take more than a microsecond extra.  It could well cost only 100 ns extra, depending on the CPU speed.  Typically power supplies give 25+ ms notice of impending power off.  This is at least 25,000 times longer than needed.

Comment: @wallyk How about context switching (from kernel to user-space and back)? It will surely take more than 100 ns. I think the whole stuff should be done in kernel exclusively.

Comment: @SamProtsenko:  data I collected for a 266 MHz ARM 7 on Linux kernel 2.4.x indicate it averaged about 3 uS to make the switch.  If your implementation supports it, call `gettimeofday()` (which offers microsecond precision) and time it yourself.

Comment: @wallyk And what if your CPU is loaded at about 100%? Are you sure that your read/write call will be handled first and will not be put in the end of scheduler queue? Doing stuff in kernel allows us to get rid of context switches completely (assuming everything is done in interrupt). So doing everything in hard IRQ *almost* guarantee that system will be powered off in 10 ms after failure signal arrived. Any other implementation (which messing with scheduler) can lead to bigger lag. So my point is, because Linux is not RTOS, failure handling should be done in hard IRQ handler.

Comment: This is an interesting way of getting a "signal" back to a user space process for the kernel, and might be perfect for another requirement I have. So, thank you @wallyk.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the root cause of my issue was a misconfigured pin (the one the interrupt signal was on), and my interrupt wasn't event occuring... I was looking at the rails coming down themselves uncontrolled. I'm guessing I messed this up while I was working on another part of the system...

I ended up using the following function to implement my delay in the hard interrupt. It's not sexy, but it does work and it's simple, and I believe the shift operation avoids overflow as pointed out in a comment by @specializt.

This code is very specific to a single piece of equipment, and the testing I've done today shows it to be pretty stable.

```
/* This is my attempt at a delay function. */
/* A count of 8 is approximately 100 microseconds */
static void delay(int delay_count)
{
    volatile u_int32_t random;
    volatile u_int64_t accum;
    volatile u_int32_t i;

    accum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < delay_count; i++) 
    {
    get_random_bytes((void*)&random, 4);
        accum = accum * random;
    accum = accum >> 32;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, why don't use `udelay()`? Even with correct implementation, it nothing but reinventing the wheel. No?

Comment: @SamProtsenko You're absolutely right. See my comment on your answer :)